# How to Call Default Windows Print Dialog Box using Tkinter/Python?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

Good day,

I am currently working on a small desktop application using Tkinter. Is there a way on how to open the default Windows Print Dialog Box using Python? Something that looks like this. I am currently exploring the win32api library but I can't seem to find the answer.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to invoke `win32api.ShellExecute` with the `"print"` verb, see [this page](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html) for more details